# Solve the equation $\sqrt{3\sqrt[3]{x}+1}=\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{x+1}-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, radical-equations

Solve the equation $\sqrt{3\sqrt[3]{x}+1}=\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{x+1}-1}$.

My attempt:
With $u=\sqrt[3]{x}, v=\sqrt{x+1}$ I have $u^3=v^2-1$ and $(3u+1)^3=(2v-1)^2$
And I finally have a quadratic equation of u in terms of v. But the $\Delta$ is not $a^2$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $x=0$ is a solution

Comment: There is also a less efficient method:$\sqrt{3\sqrt[3]{x}+1}=\lambda\Big/^2\iff3\sqrt[3]{x}+1=\lambda^2\iff \sqrt[3]{x}=\frac{\lambda^2-1}{3}\Big/^3\iff x=\frac{(\lambda^2-1)^3}{27}$

$\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{x+1}-1}=\lambda\Big/^3\iff2\sqrt{x+1}-1=\lambda^3\iff\sqrt{x+1}=\frac{\lambda^3+1}{2}\Big/^2\iff x=\frac{(\lambda^3+1)^2-4}{4}$

$\implies \frac{(\lambda^2-1)^3}{27}=\frac{(\lambda^3-1)(\lambda^3+3)}{4}$
so $x=0$ for $\lambda=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sqrt[3]x=a$.

Thus, we need to solve
$$(3a+1)^3=\left(2\sqrt{a^3+1}-1\right)^2$$ or
$$23a^3+27a^2+9a=4(1-\sqrt{a^3+1})$$ or
$$a\left(23a^2+27a+9+\frac{4a^2}{1+\sqrt{a^3+1}}\right)=0,$$ which since $$27^2-4\cdot23\cdot9<0,$$ gives $$a=0$$ and $$x=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: @Nguyen Thy You are welcome!